# SQL Connection error in Bluemix:Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a:679'

Tags: java, database, web-services, db2, ibm-cloud

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZxQ0.jpg)Please find the [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZxQ0.jpg) for the error details while connecting SQL DB in Blue mix

Please find the below sample code

`<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource"%>`

`String username = request.getParameter("username");

    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Connection con=null;
    DB2SimpleDataSource dataSource = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
    String databaseHost="75.126.155.153";
    int port=50000;
    String databaseName="SQLDB";
    String user="*****";
    String pword="*****";
    dataSource.setServerName(databaseHost);
    dataSource.setPortNumber(port);
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    dataSource.setUser(user);
    dataSource.setPassword (pword);
    dataSource.setDriverType(4);
    con=dataSource.getConnection();`

Comment: you should provide more details about your issue. How are you connecting your APP to db instance (code snippet) ? What runtime are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

The SQLCODE -204 means "Undefined name". It is a DB2 error code indicating 'object does not exist'. The SQLERRMC value helps provides you more specific information. In your case what can't be found is the table *USER14336.DDP_DIR*. Double check the schema name (*USER14336*) and the table name (*DDP_DIR*). Please check also the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable of your application to see if you are using the correct username (as schema name). You can also omit the schema name if there is only one (in this case DB2 uses the default one).